# I need a scripting language that can be hosted by a .net application with the following features

Tags: c#, .net, scripting-language

- I need to be able to expose "commands" that make calls to the host.
- I need to have simple easy to read syntax.
- It needs to be easy to pick up by non-programmers.

An example would be as follows:

**Host Application:**

```
ScriptHost.AddCommandBinding("MyCommand", delegateToMyHandler, parameterDefinitionsStruct);
```

**Script**

```
 returnval = MyCommand(param1, param2);
```

anybody know of anything like this?

Comment: I think  you're dreaming if you think you're going to find "easy to pick up by non-programmers". "Easy to abuse", maybe, but once you get far beyond sequential execution, scripts are programs, and are written by programmers. Written well, or written badly.

Comment: yeah sequential execution and limited api sounds about right :-P

Comment: @John: The business world is full of people who are happy to script Excel but wouldn't call themselves programmers.

Answer (score 2):

[IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython) would be perfect for this.

The book description for [IronPython in Action](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781933988337) says *"You'll learn how IronPython can be embedded as a ready-made scripting language into C# and VB.NET programs"*.

Comment: having looked at the documentation I can't see how to add functions to iron python that map to .net object methods.

Comment: @firoso: Sorry, I don't know the details, I only know it's possible to do, and that Python would be a good language choice for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using PowerShell, if any of your non-programmers are system administrators. It's being used as the built-in scripting language for Exchange Server and SQL Server, and ships with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: yeah, try electronic test technicians.

Comment: sounds like a bad match for me.

Comment: Certainly, the syntax is more messy than I'd like, and honestly powershell is designed more for IT professionals, not hardware engineers.

Comment: ok, thanks. I would have thought an object pipeline would be just what they'd like: get-service | where {$_.DisplayName -like 'sql*' -and $_.Status -eq 'Running'} | stop-service -force -verbose